# Enable SSLv3 in Minikube Nginx Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, ingress, minikube

I have some problems with enabling SSLv3 in my Nginx Ingress used as a Minikube addon.
I have read in [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#legacy-tls) how to do it. It should be as simple as adding single map.
Unfortunately I haven't had much success with it. It added this map in both namespaces - kube-system and the second one in which ingress is created.

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
data:
  ssl-ciphers: "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA"
  ssl-protocols: "SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3"
```

I did it separately and even forced nginx-ingress-controller but nothing happened. I have also found out about nginx-load-balancer-conf ConfigMap in kube-system namespace and added the same entries there too, but it didn't help either.

ssl-protocols seems to be one of few properties which can be defined in [ConfigMap](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/configmap-resource/) but no by [annotations](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/).

So my question is: Am I making some kind of stupid mistake or Minikube requires some different configuration?

I'm checking result of my actions by [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh).

@Update
I have listed my ingress controller config and there is my list of enabled ssl-protocols containing all I lisited, so I guess config is read, but not used. I have also read the logs but there is no errors there suggesting that for some reason SSLv3 cannot be used.

```
user@server:~$ kubectl exec -it -n kube-system nginx-ingress-controller-658b646bc5-4h562 cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep ssl
            is_ssl_passthrough_enabled = false,
        listen_ports = { ssl_proxy = "442", https = "443" },
    ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
```